# Trying to decipher a hexadecimal code

Tags: javascript, encryption, hex

I have been doing a programming challenge and i'm on the final question, which involves deciphering a hexadecimal code to reveal a secret code. the answer must start with 0x so it must be another hexadecimal value but i am unable to figure out how to decipher the following hex value:

0xB105F00D 0x6FA83E1C

Some help on how to decipher this code or the deciphered message would be very helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString). Specifically the `Radix` option should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the whole content of the task?

Did you try to perform basic bit operations (or, and, nand, etc...) on these values?

Maybe the answer is **0x215231EE** because

**0xB105F00D** *XNOR* **0x215231EE** *===* **0x6FA83E1C**

From the guidelines you provided, it is difficult to guess the answer without knowing the profile and type of tasks you had.

Because the answer is to be the hexadecimal value, I think you should find a correlation between your values, taking into account other forms of writing.

Comment: (The opposite of XNOR might be a better choice...)

Comment: then (xor) you will get a value **0xDEADCE11**

Comment: Exactly! (But I wasn't going to make it that easy.)